# How to print multiple variable created inside function of class in php

Tags: php, class

I have follwing class in file "`super.class.php`"

```
<?php    
class super {

        public function loadme() {
            $tilt = "I am tilted";
            $straight = "I am Straight";
            $round = "I am round";
            $sleep = "I am Sleeping";
        }

        public function fireme() {
            $hit = "I am hit";
            $bullet = "I got bullet";
            $gun = "Cover me! I am receiving Heavy Firing";
        }
}
?>
```

I want to print each variable in my other file. **Note:** Classes are called from `spl_autoload_register`

When I am trying to print :-

```
<?php
    $obj_super = new super();
    echo $obj_super->loadme()->tilt;
    echo $obj_super->fireme()->hit;
?>
```

I am getting error :- `Trying to get property of non-object in agent.php`

## **Update: I got it working via this**

Hope I am not doing any wrong below :-

```
<?php    
    class super {

        public $title = array();
        public $situation = array();

        public function loadme() {
            $this->title['tilt'] = "I am tilted";
            $this->title['straight'] = "I am Straight";
            $this->title['round'] = "I am round";
            $this->title['sleep'] = "I am Sleeping"; 
            return $this->title;
        }

        public function fireme() {
            $this->situation['hit'] = "I am hit";
            $this->situation['bullet'] = "I got bullet";
            $this->situation['gun'] = "Cover me! I am receiving Heavy Firing";
            return $this->situation;
        }
    }
    ?>

    <?php
        $obj_super = new super();
        $value = $obj_super->loadme();
        echo $value['tilt'];
    ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: All those are _local_ variables, they're not attached to the instance. `$this->tilt = ...`, etc...

Comment: i even tried using `public $variable` and than `global $variable` inside function , it's still not working :(

Comment: If you *really* want to do it this way, you need to create a new object in each method (e.g. `stdClass`) and assign the local variables to it as properties, then return that object. It's very messy though - what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Try setting each variable `public` or declare them as public instance variables.

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton: Right, or run the method then access the public variable.

Comment: avoid `global`. it is pure evil.

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton , bro , can i return multiple variable in function ?

Comment: Johny, no. @elclanrs I think making them public properties would be even worse. At the moment it's looking like loadme and fireme should each be a separate class.

Comment: I got it working via this http://phpfiddle.org/api/raw/xw7-smb . Hope I am not doing any wrong there.. If it is right can someone post this, so that i can accept as answer. I am not able to add my answer because of my less reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested - the answer from Johny Bravo.

```
class super {

    public $title = array();
    public $situation = array();

    public function loadme() {
        $this->title['tilt'] = "I am tilted";
        $this->title['straight'] = "I am Straight";
        $this->title['round'] = "I am round";
        $this->title['sleep'] = "I am Sleeping"; 
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function fireme() {
        $this->situation['hit'] = "I am hit";
        $this->situation['bullet'] = "I got bullet";
        $this->situation['gun'] = "Cover me! I am receiving Heavy Firing";
        return $this->situation;
    }
}


$obj_super = new super();
$value = $obj_super->loadme();
echo $value['tilt'];
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I am just hoping this code does not make my page load slow :( :)

Comment: you seem overly concerned about the loading speed of your page - none of the discussed methods will have a measurable delay on your pages. Arguably - the above code will be the SLOWEST, as you are having to locate and assign a value to an associative array each time you access a function, then re-access that associative array when you want to print.

Comment: @JohnyBravo: Performance isn't an issue til it is.  Worry about getting stuff working, and don't fret too much over the speed of your page til you can point to a particular problem with it.

Comment: Bug free, Security and faster performance is all my top 3 concern for which i am always coding bro. :) to me every second matters :)

Comment: well, again - this is a great way to cause bugs down the road, as your doing something pretty strange here, also - as I said before, this is likely to be the slowest method. And has no impact on security at all.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the variables into your class, like so:

```
class super {
    public $tilt;
    public $straight;
}
```

And then set them with

```
public function loadme(){
    $this->tilt = "I am tilted";
    $this->straight = "I am straight";
}
```

You can get them with

```
$new = new super;
$new->loadme();
echo $new->tilt;
```

Comment: I need to call it only with the help of function :(

Comment: If you set them in the function, like `public function(){ $this->tilt = 'whatever'; }` then you can do `$new->function();` and then `echo $new->tilt;`

Comment: I got it working via this http://phpfiddle.org/api/raw/xw7-smb . Hope I am not doing any wrong there.. If it is right can someone post this, so that i can accept as answer. I am not able to add my answer because of my less reputation

Answer (score 2):

Ok, you seem to have misunderstood how functions work in PHP - the variables you have declared in your functions are local to the function - i.e. they only have a value inside the functions scope.

Secondly, the notation `$obj_super->loadme()->tilt` will give the value of the property `tilt` of the return of `loadme()` since `loadme()` doesnt return anything - you are essentially doing this `null->tilt`. Which likely causes all sorts of errors if you check your log.

What is it you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: What do you mean by `property` of `return` ? Where did you read that ? It is property of object inside which function defined as a method, i.e. `$this->property`.

Comment: Well, if I return an object in my method, then use the -> operator, I access the property of the object I returned.

Comment: Can i return multiple variable from function ?

Comment: @ZackNewsham sorry misunderstood that. Could you please add an example?

Comment: Only within an object, or an array, so you could do this

    $ret = new stdClass();
    $ret->variable = "value";
    return $ret;

Comment: @CORRUPT, sure, its hard to format in comments: 

function giveObject(){$object = new stdClass(); $object->variable = "test"; return $object;}

echo giveObject()->variable; will echo "test"

Comment: I got it working via this http://phpfiddle.org/api/raw/xw7-smb . Hope I am not doing any wrong there.. If it is right can someone post this, so that i can accept as answer. I am not able to add my answer because of my less reputation

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can design a class like this

```
<?php    
    class super {
        private $_tilt; 
        private $_straight;
        private $_round;
        private $_sleep;

        private $_hit;
        private $_bullet;
        private $_gun;

        public function loadme() {
            $this->_tilt = "I am tilted";
            $this->_straight = "I am Straight";
            $this->_round = "I am round";
            $this->_sleep = "I am Sleeping";
        }

        public function fireme() {
            $this->_hit = "I am hit";
            $this->_bullet = "I got bullet";
            $this->_gun = "Cover me! I am receiving Heavy Firing";
        }

        public function getTilt() {
            return $this->_tilt;
        }

        // Other getter functions
    }
?>
```

Then invoke the getter functions

```
<?php
    $oSuper = new super;
    $oSuper->loadme();
    echo $oSuper->getTilt();
?>
```

Comment: I don't want to use getter fucntion for each variable, it will make my page slow i guess. ?

Comment: www.google.com/search?q=website+optimisation+php+google+developer

Comment: I got it working via this http://phpfiddle.org/api/raw/xw7-smb . Hope I am not doing any wrong there.. If it is right can someone post this, so that i can accept as answer. I am not able to add my answer because of my less reputation

Answer (score 1):

if you want to call it the exact way you are calling it you can return the object itself from each function. Try the following

```
class super {
    public $tilt = '';
    public $straight = '';
    public $round = '';
    public $sleep = '';
    public $hit = '';
    public $bullet = '';
    public $gun = '';
    public function loadme() {
        $this -> tilt = "I am tilted";
        $this -> straight = "I am Straight";
        $this -> round = "I am round";
        $this -> sleep = "I am Sleeping";
        return $this;
    }

    public function fireme() {
        $this -> hit = "I am hit";
        $this -> bullet = "I got bullet";
        $this -> gun = "Cover me! I am receiving Heavy Firing";
        return $this;
    }

}

$obj_super = new super();
echo $obj_super -> loadme() -> tilt;
echo $obj_super -> fireme() -> hit;
```

again as @TheNytangel suggested the following also will work with this class. if you want to suppress this behavior also you may need to redesign your functions as objects.

```
$obj_super = new super();
$obj_super -> loadme();
echo $obj_super -> tilt;
$obj_super -> fireme();
echo $obj_super  -> hit;
```

Comment: are you getting any error messages? I tested it before posting and it was working for me

Comment: NO Error with no value.. Blank my php version 5.4.9

Comment: I am using PHP 5.4.16 and the code i posted works for me! i don't think the PHP version matters as this is very basic class and works on all PHP version unless it is before OOP support. The output I get is `I am tiltedI am hit`

Comment: I got it working via this http://phpfiddle.org/api/raw/xw7-smb . Hope I am not doing any wrong there.. If it is right can someone post this, so that i can accept as answer. I am not able to add my answer because of my less reputation

Comment: if you are going to return the values in an array you don't need instance variables. check this fiddle http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5qe-hn6

Answer (score 0):

As per OP's code in fiddle with modification. I have removed the instance variables. New fiddle here http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5qe-hn6

```
<?php    
class super {

    public function loadme() {
        $title=array();
        $title['tilt'] = "I am tilted";
        $title['straight'] = "I am Straight";
        $title['round'] = "I am round";
        $title['sleep'] = "I am Sleeping"; 
        return $title;
    }

    public function fireme() {
        $situation=array();
        $situation['hit'] = "I am hit";
        $situation['bullet'] = "I got bullet";
        $situation['gun'] = "Cover me! I am receiving Heavy Firing";
        return $situation;
    }
}
?>

<?php
    $obj_super = new super();
    $value = $obj_super->loadme();
    echo $value['tilt'];
?>
```

Comment: wow.. :) thank you so much sir. 

offtopic :  are you really coding from last 24 year, where in India you are from, do you have any blog or so, i would like to visit them. :)

Comment: yes i started programming with 'Acorn Atom' and 'BBC Micro'. sry currently don't have my blog site up.